# How to speed up forloop grep in a large dataframe using R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data.table

Please I need help.

I have I script that works well for many dataframes even if that takes several hours (on the cluster: **> 100 GB memory**). For some large dataframes (**> 3 Million rows** ) the loop for doesn't work even after two days of running.
So, I need help if there is a way to speed up the for loop or replace the script with more speeder functions in R.

This is a short description of my script/data:

```
    snp1 <- c("R0100004", "R0100009", "R0100044", "R0100061", "R0100066","R0100067") # 3 million SNPs
    snp2 <- c("R0100039", "R0100152", "R0100066", "R0100067", "R0100068", "R0100082") # 3 million SNPs
    
    blocks <- c("R0100004|R0100009|R0100190|R0100015|R0100016|R0100017|R0100018|R0100021|R0100022|R0100024|R0100025",
                "R0100039|R0100038|R0100037|R0100036|R0100043|R0100044",                                   
                "R0100220|R0100052|R0100053|R0100054|R0100055|R0100057|R0100058|R0100059",                         
                "R0100061|R0100066|R0100067",                                                                      
                "R0100068|R0100069|R0100071|R0100072|R0100073|R0100074|R0133440|R0100076|R0100077|R0100078",         
                "R0100079|R0100081|R0100082") # 50000 haplotype block: each block contain > 2 SNPs. The SNP could be in 2 or more blocks.

# THE OBJECTIVE: For each SNP (snp1 and snp2) find his haplotype block    
    # This is my forloop
    I <- length(snp1) # 3000000
    res1 <- list()
    res2 <- list()
    for(j in 1:I){ 
        myres1 <- list(grep(snp1[j], blocks, value=T))
        myres2 <- list(grep(snp2[j], blocks, value=T))
        res1[j] <- myres1
        res2[j] <- myres2
    }
```

The for loop works well for medium dataframes, but for dataframes with large rows it takes several days.
How can I replace or speed up this for loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might to by a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to answer/solve?

Comment: What I am trying is: for each snp  (snp1 and snp2) determine its block from the dataframe ( blocks).

Comment: Does my answer achieve what you need?

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny I get the **by` can't contain join column blocks2 which is missing from RHS** error. Do you have an idea about the source of the error? Thanks

Comment: No clue. I have just run the code on a different computer, and it works without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried completely different approach and deliberately increased the size of your data by 500. The solution I propose is 5 times faster for 500 times larger dataset, and should be more and more faster if the size of the data increase.

```
library(tidyverse)

scale_factor <- 500 # to basically make your objects larger

# recreating your objects, but scaling them using the scaling_factor
snp1 <- c("R0100004", "R0100009", "R0100044", "R0100061", "R0100066","R0100067") %>% rep(scale_factor)
snp2 <- c("R0100039", "R0100152", "R0100066", "R0100067", "R0100068", "R0100082") %>% rep(scale_factor)

blocks <- c("R0100004|R0100009|R0100190|R0100015|R0100016|R0100017|R0100018|R0100021|R0100022|R0100024|R0100025",
            "R0100039|R0100038|R0100037|R0100036|R0100043|R0100044",                                   
            "R0100220|R0100052|R0100053|R0100054|R0100055|R0100057|R0100058|R0100059",                         
            "R0100061|R0100066|R0100067",                                                                      
            "R0100068|R0100069|R0100071|R0100072|R0100073|R0100074|R0133440|R0100076|R0100077|R0100078",         
            "R0100079|R0100081|R0100082")

# this is your original code
original <- function(snp1, snp2, blocks){
  # This is my forloop
  I <- length(snp1) # 3000000
  res1 <- list()
  res2 <- list()
  for(j in 1:I){ 
    myres1 <- list(grep(snp1[j], blocks, value=T))
    myres2 <- list(grep(snp2[j], blocks, value=T))
    res1[j] <- myres1
    res2[j] <- myres2
  }
  
}

tuned <- function(snp1, snp2, blocks){
  
  df1 <- data.frame(snp1)
  df2 <- data.frame(snp2)
  
  df_blocks <- data.frame(blocks) %>%
    mutate(blocks2 = blocks %>% str_split("\\|")) %>%
    unnest(cols = c(blocks2))
  
  res1 <- left_join(df1, df_blocks, by = c("snp1" = "blocks2")) %>%
    pull(blocks) %>%
    map(~.x)
  
  res2 <- left_join(df2, df_blocks, by = c("snp2" = "blocks2")) %>%
    pull(blocks) %>%
    map(~.x)

  
}

# this benchmarks both solutions
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(original(snp1, snp2, blocks), tuned(snp1, snp2, blocks))
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
# original(snp1, snp2, blocks) 63.0723 65.65775 71.18956 69.3941 73.14755 102.5951   100
# tuned(snp1, snp2, blocks) 13.3522 14.39015 16.24824 15.5053 16.17280  33.6679   100
```

Comment: Thank You I will try it. But I don't think that should make a large difference for my real dataframe (> 3 million rows), in terms of running time.

Comment: Ab_Lh: I changed my answer completely. Now it should be faster than your solution for a larger dataset.

Comment: I tried to run the script but I still get error msg:    `res1 <- left_join(df1, df_blocks, by = c("snp1" = "blocks2")) %>%
+     pull(blocks) %>%
+     map(~.x)
Erreur : `by` can't contain join column `blocks2` which is missing from RHS`

Comment: Thank you. In fact, there was a problem with R version in the server. I updated some packages and I added the `stringsAsFacto=FALSE` to the `data.frame(blocks)`.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will be fast but might not be doing precisely what you want.

I've assumed things based on the sample data - e.g. that each `snp1` or `snp2` value only appears in at most one of the blocks, and that `blocks` is much shorter than `snp1`, `snp2`.

```
library(data.table)
y <- data.table(block = blocks)[,
  .(Rnum = unlist(strsplit(block, "\\|"))),
  .(block)]
res1 <- as.list(y[snp1, on = 'Rnum', block])
res2 <- as.list(y[snp2, on = 'Rnum', block])
```

If my assumptions are wrong just let me know.

However, I strongly suspect that if you describe what you are actually trying to do there will be a much better solution than this.

Comment: Thank you. In fact the snp could be in many other blocs. And blocks are composed of several snps. The @Jakub 's solution works well.